# How can Tina Minoru’s timeline be reconciled?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange-2016, runaways-2017

We know that Tina Minoru [appears in *Doctor Strange*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/144977/51379), and also in the *Runaways* TV series, in which she is portrayed by a different actor. The two works are both set in the MCU. However, there are parts of the timeline that I don’t understand.

- The linked question suggests that Minoru’s appearance in *Doctor Strange* precedes her arc on *Runaways*. But how much wiggle room is there between the show and film: a year, perhaps three? She’s clearly belonged to Pride for a long time, and seemingly came in at roughly the same time as most of the others: she was there at what appeared to be the Wilders’ first Pride meeting. And the Wilders joined Pride before Alex was born….
- In *Runaways*, she describes the Staff of One as technology (though it *is* clearly magical; as Nico says, high-tech magic) created in Wizard Labs. There’s no reason that they couldn’t have created a new magical artifact in a laboratory, but she has the staff in *Doctor Strange*, which is presumably before she joined Pride. So is she lying to Nico about the staff’s origins (why?). Or was it somehow created before she joined Pride (how?)

How can this character’s characteristics and timeline in the two works, set in the same continuity, be reconciled? Has there been an official comment on this aspect specifically?

Comment: There are loads of overlaps in the MCU timeline already. I wouldn't be surprised if _Runaways_ is running concurrent to everything else, including _Doctor Strange_

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - Then the question becomes why Tina took a break from her business and Pride activities to go to Asia and fight Kaecilius etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this interview](http://au.ign.com/articles/2017/08/01/marvels-runaways-is-the-oc-of-the-mcu) the creators of the show more or less dismiss the appearance of Tina in Doctor Strange, saying she was only named in the credits. She does appear in one of the prequel comics briefly though, however the comic doesn't establish any kind of time period other than being before the movie, so it is less of conflict with this portrayal. It is possible that this is just a retcon about the appearance in the film and there is no intended continuity.

Comment: Actually, I am fairly sure she is in one of the prequel works.

Comment: @Adamant The one I checked didn't. Found and checked the other prequel series and there she was.

Comment: If I had to retcon things, I'd say that the Staff of One is built along certain magical principles, like the Infinity Gauntlet, such that anyone can make one in theory, with the right tools and magical talent. Discarding Tina's name from the credits of *Doctor Strange*, she could then have been a totally different person with a staff made along similar principles.

Answer (score -1):

I have a theory. Tina has a sister named Christina. Both sisters dislike each other and have a terrible relationship. After collage, Christina discovers Kamar Taj and becomes Master of the Mystic Arts. Her artifact is the Staff of One. Jealous of her sister, Tina has the lab recreate the staff with nanotechnology. Mystery solved!

Comment: That makes more sense than whatever the writers had in mind, I’m sure.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gISEekxuEgk