# Why did Nico embrace Dormammu in Runaways S02E10?

Tags: doctor-strange-2016, runaways, runaways-2017

In S02E10 of *Runaways*, Nico has exhausted herself defending the shelter, but her body snaps into guard position and she uses her staff to destroy the enemies.  After her body snaps upright and before she destroys the strike force, her face scales around the eyes in exactly the manner that Dormammu's adherents did in *Dr. Strange*:

[image: Scaly eyed Nico]

Is this ever explained?  Given that (insofar as loose canon applies) [her mother opposed Dormammu](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/144977/20490), and without any indicator that Nico had any connection with Dormammu within [runaways-2017], what could possibly explain this burst of power in her?  There's no indication within [runaways-2017] of Nico interacting with adherents of Dormammu, or with any other magical adherents, for that matter.

Answers from the comic version [runaways] are perfectly acceptable.