# Are these Dark Dimensions the same?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange-2016, runaways-2017, cloak-and-dagger

The Dark Dimension shows up in *Doctor Strange*, *Runaways*, and *Cloak and Dagger*. Now, when Nico uses the staff, her eyes and the area around them develop a pattern very similar to that of Kaecilius and the others who drew power from the Dark Dimension, suggesting that it is the same one. On the other hand, visually and thematically the dimensions are not very similar: the one in *Doctor Strange* is controlled by (and *is*) Dread Dormammu, is decorated in psychedelic colors, and prevents aging; the one in *Runaways* is a shadowy reflection of the physical realm that shows people their nightmares and makes them forget who they are; the one on *Cloak and Dagger* is similar *but* does not appear to cause forgetfulness, and the nightmares appear to only show up when one of the loa that hang out there causes them.

It is fairly clear that the dimension that Tandy and Tyrone visit in their own show is the same as the Dark Dimension shown on *Runaways*, despite certain differences, but is it the same as the Dark Dimension from *Doctor Strange*? What explains the differing manifestations? Is the Dark Dimension like an apartment block that someone (Dormammu or someone else) leases out to tenants who set their own place up according to their tastes?

Comment: Also, is there any relationship between the two Darkholds?

Comment: I believe that there has been confirmation that they are officially (Darkhold too) but I am having trouble tracking it down.

Comment: Every time someone finds *a* dark dimension they decide it's *The Dark Dimension* ‍♂️

Comment: Related, unanswered: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/202915/20490

Comment: On the Darkhold, I believe [that's now a book in the MCU](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244226/origins-of-the-book-used-by-wanda-in-the-post-credit-scene#comment670543_244226)