# Are there any differences between the two "Darkholds" in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness, wandavision

In *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, and again in *WandaVision* and *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*, the book called "the Darkhold" is used and heavily affects the plot.

However, they both have different appearances, as seen below:

[image: Two different versions of the "Darkhold"]

What is actually different about these two books? It seems as if they contain the same powers, so why are their appearances different?

Comment: Related: [Origins of the book used by Wanda in the post credit scene?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/244226/7957)

Comment: The one in _WandaVision_ is a bit darker, but then the one in _S.H.I.E.L.D._ holds a bit more, so it's swings and roundabouts really. _Evil_ swings and roundabouts.

Comment: If I recall correctly, there's a third version in *Runaways*.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots the one in *Runaways* is the same prop as *Agents of Shield*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The book, the Darkhold, as explained in *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* is actually a copy of the spells carved into the walls at Mount Wundagore. As such the physical difference between the two books is easily explained by them just being two separate copies of the same spells. They're not the same physical book but the contents are the same.

> **Wong:** The Darkhold was a copy!
>
> **Wanda:** A copy?
>
> **Wong:** Legend speaks of a mountain with the wretched spells you seek carved into its walls. It's there the Darkhold was transcribed. Mount Wundagore.
>
> <sub>*Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*</sub>

Comment: ISBN or GTFO bro

Comment: The name on the S.H.I.E.L.D. version being an [ambigram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambigram) is interesting, though it's only an ambigram in *English*, which doesn't exactly make sense if this thing has other-worldly origins.  So the idea of this just being another copy with a different cover holds up.

Answer (score 5):

#### The Darkhold from *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* and *Runaways* is not part of the main MCU timeline.

The book *[Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline](https://books.google.com/books/about/Marvel_Studios_the_Marvel_Cinematic_Univ.html?id=aeqSzwEACAAJ)* documents the events, characters, and items that belong to the main MCU timeline, also known as “616” or the “Sacred Timeline.”

This book does not feature anything from *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* or *Runaways*, which implies that they are set in alternate timelines from 616. Therefore, the Darkhold that appears in those shows is not the same as the one that appears in *WandaVision* and *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness*, and that explains why they have different appearances.